# Not working: Copy HTML signature to clipboard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard.js

How can I make the "copy to clipboard" button work for an outcome of my HTML + Javascript? I've read different posts and tried this, but it isn't working for me:

```
<button type="button" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#copy">Copy</button>
<script>
 (function(){
    new Clipboard('#copy-button');
})();
</script>  
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.4.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

The goal is to create an email signature tool - complete the fields, press the copy button and paste it into your email client's signature creator.

Here's the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/t7y5uq89/

(Apologies in advance for the mix of HTML+Javascript in one file -- I'm a self educated coder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `new Clipboard` inside a self-invoking function, which won't work because it is executed before the DOM is loaded. Instead you should wrap it in the "document ready" event:

```js
$(function() {
    new Clipboard('#copy-button');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#copy">Copy</button>

<div id="copy">
    <h1>John Foo</h1>
</div>
```

I would also like to criticize your HTML markup:

- There is basically no semantics in your code. For example, you should use `<label>` tags to indicate input labels, not `<b>` tags (which have been deprecated for more than a decade).
- You should specify one global font, not repeat yourself on each tag. This is as simple as:

  ```
  body {
      font: 12px 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  ```

  Also notice font names with spaces require quotes around them.
- Do not use inline styles.
- Don't mix HTML with Javascript. Why? For maintainability of the code, and to make it easier to read. This is most likely the reason why nobody took the time to answer your question.
- Close your HTML tags properly.

Comment: Hi Midas, thanks for your feedback! The copy function is working, but now the onkeyup functionality doesn't work anymore. Any idea?

I've changed the code: first I've added the global font to CSS, then splitted the CSS and Javascript from the HTML which makes it work much easier. 

New version: https://jsfiddle.net/Tommy_86/vgLrg0h4

Comment: @Tom You need to change the JSFiddle settings of the Javascript panel. It is set to wrap all JS code in the `onload` event but this should be set to "wrap - in <head>". Wrap in `onload` is useful only if you're fiddle doesn't use any functions.